# Instantiate prefab randomly but not in already occupied position

Tags: unity, unityscript

I want to generate bubbles randomly on screen. When a bubble is generated in one place then other bubbles should not be generated near its radius 1 area, so they can not collide or trigger with any other bubbles.

How can I do it ?

```
public void GenerateBubble ()
{
    newBubbleXPos = Random.Range (-7, 7);
    newBubbleYPos = Random.Range (-3, 3);
    bubbleClone = (GameObject)Instantiate (bubblePrefab, new Vector3 (newBubbleXPos, newBubbleYPos, 0), Quaternion.identity);
    UIManager.instance.ChangeBubbleSprite (bubbleClone);
    bubbleList.Add (bubbleClone);
    if (bubblePosList.Contains (bubbleClone.transform.position)) {
        bubbleClone.transform.position=new Vector3(Random.Range (-7,7),Random.Range (-3,3),0);
    }
    bubblePosList.Add (bubbleClone.transform.position);
    bubbleClone.transform.parent = UIManager.instance.CurrentLevel.transform;
    GLOBALS.bubbleCounter++;
}
```

In this code every bubble is generated in a different position, but they can collide with other bubbles.  I want to generate new bubbles not at the same position. My bubble colliders's radius is 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found Answer :

```
  public List<GameObject> bubbleList = new List<GameObject> ();
    private int newBubbleXPos;
    private int newBubbleYPos;

public void GenerateBubble ()
    {
        bool locationInvaild = true;
        while (locationInvaild) {
            newBubbleXPos = Random.Range (-8, 8);
            newBubbleYPos = Random.Range (-4, 4);
            currentPosition = new Vector3 (newBubbleXPos, newBubbleYPos, 0);
            locationInvaild = false;
            for (int i=0; i<bubbleList.Count; i++) {
                if (Vector3.Distance (bubbleList [i].transform.position, currentPosition) < 2.5f * radius) {
                    locationInvaild = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        bubbleClone = Instantiate (bubblePrefab, new Vector3 (newBubbleXPos, newBubbleYPos, 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        bubbleList.Add (bubbleClone);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There you go.

1. You need to check against all of the positions
2. Compute the distance between them and check whether it's valid or not
3. If everything fails because there are too much bubbles, you need to finish it; whether generating the bubble or deciding not to do it.

Here:

```
public void GenerateBubble ()
{
    float validDistance = 1.0f;
    bool isValidPos = false;
    int tryouts = 100;
    Vector3 newPos = new Vector3();
    while (!isValidPos)
    {
        tryouts--;
        isValidPos = true;
        float newBubbleXPos = Random.Range (-7f, 7f);
        float newBubbleYPos = Random.Range (-3f, 3f);
        Vector3 newPos = new Vector3(newBubbleXPos, newBubbleYPos);
        foreach (Vector3 p in bubblePosList)
        {
            Vector3 direction = p - newPos;
            float sqrDistance = direction.sqrMagnitude;
            if (sqrDistance < validDistance * validDistance)
            {
                isValidPos = false;
                // no need to check further, but generate new position
                break;
            }
        }
        // you don't want an infinite loop when things go unexpectedly wrong
        // you could choose between one the following approaches
        // approach 1: don't generate anything
        if (tryouts == 0 && !isValidPos)
            return;
        // ******************************
        // approach 2: get the last position generated and go with it
        if (tryouts == 0 && !isValidPos)
            break;
        // ******************************
    }
    GameObject bubbleClone = (GameObject)Instantiate (bubblePrefab, newPos, Quaternion.identity);
    UIManager.instance.ChangeBubbleSprite (bubbleClone);
    bubbleList.Add (bubbleClone);
    bubblePosList.Add (bubbleClone.transform.position);
    bubbleClone.transform.parent = UIManager.instance.CurrentLevel.transform;
    GLOBALS.bubbleCounter++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` should probably be a `do...while` (what happens if you are really unlucky and you get another invalid coordinate?).

For the radius, if you maintain a list of bubbles placed, then check whether you new point is within 1 of any of them, then choose another number

E.g your code might look something like:

```
public void GenerateBubble ()
{
    do
    {
         newBubbleXPos = Random.Range (-7, 7);
         newBubbleYPos = Random.Range (-3, 3);
         bool bubbleTooClose = false;
         foreach(GameObject existingBubble in bubbleList)
         {
             float Distance = (existingBubble.transform.position - new Vector3(newBubbleXPos, newBubbleYPos, 0)).sqrMagnitude;
             if(Distance < 1)
             {
                 bubbleTooClose = true;
                 break;
             }
         }

         if(!bubbleTooClose)
         {
             break;
         }
     }
     while(true);

     // now can spawn the bubble with the positions as no bubbles too close
     // remember to add to bubbleList
}
```

Note, we can use `sqrMagnitude` rather than `magnitude` since 1 x 1 = 1. If you wanted a different radius, you would need to square the radius. E.g. if you didn't want bubbles within 2 units of any others, you would check `if(Distance < 2 * 2)`

Comment: Here you use lengthSquared() what is it?

Comment: Sorry not used Unity in a while, it should be `sqrMagnitude`, I'll update the answer